# PowerBI or Excel : create columns based on unique values in column

Tags: powerquery

I have an Excel file with translations in the following format:

```
Field       |  Language  |  Translation
startbutton    English      Start
startbutton    French       Démarrer
stopbutton     English      Stop
stopbutton     French       Arrêter
```

But I would like to have it in this format:

```
Field       |  English   |  French
startbutton    Start        Démarrer
stopbutton     Stop         Arrêter
```

**How can this be achieved?** I already tried some things with PowerQuery but wasn't able to get the desired result...

Answer (score 0):

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "i45WKi5JLCpJKi0pyc9T0lFyzUvPySzOALKCQeJKsTroKtyKUvOSQQpcDq/MTSwqSi2CKsovwGpKfgGmPNwMx6Kiw6tKQEbEAgA=", 
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ), 
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ), 
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [Field = _t, Language = _t, Translation = _t]
  ), 
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source, 
    {{"Field", type text}, {"Language", type text}, {"Translation", type text}}
  ), 
  #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(
    #"Changed Type", 
    List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Language]), 
    "Language", 
    "Translation"
  )
in
  #"Pivoted Column"
```